# Asking for any/"best" program for X vs. asking how to do X with specific program, and the "X/Y Problem"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, multiple-answers

I can find myself struggling to write a question about doing Y with any of the usual GNU/*nix tools like awk, sed, tr, .. perl (not sure that's GNU/*nix..), or perhaps others I do not know of.

I saw my questions and subject lines violating the "asking for best program to do Y" no-no, but found myself struggling yet again in "asking how to do Y when X is (assumed to be) a better solution" by specifying only awk, or only sed - oh no, it violated the X/Y problem rule. So the questions are abandoned. The abandonment tends to be a good thing, but that is not necessarily as a rule.

I find this to be a flaw in the "X/Y problem" ending the question, and worse, shutting questions down before they ever get written.

What is wrong about specifying (in particular) awk, sed, perl, etc. in the subject line or question? Or in asking how to do Y with any of them - i.e. "of awk, sed, or perl, which is the best program for this specific task and setting"?

Because programs like awk or sed are doing similar tasks, but very differently, and I probably don't know a better way to do Y in awk but do know in perl (for argument's sake)? How can we group programs, or should we ask about specific ones?

Comment: Note that on MSE, [tag:linux] tag is for "using Stack Exchange on Linux environment", not "questions about Linux".

Answer (score 4):

Well - generally "I'm using [tool] to do [foo] and I'm having performance issues" is a reasonable question, and if you're sticking to a specific tool, the 'why' is a good thing. "I'm using Perl elsewhere in the script and I'd like to stick to a common environment."

The XY problem is wanting to either use an unsuitable tool or approach to a problem. If you can justify why you want to use a specific problem, or build your question around current tool use, I don't generally see an issue.

That said, if you are not tied to a specific tool, there's a lot of value in being open to ideas.

I think this [old question](https://superuser.com/questions/485800/whats-the-quickest-way-to-count-the-number-of-each-character-in-a-file/485811#485811) has some of it but...

Don't ask for a software rec. Talk about your environment (Linux), what you want to do, and the problems with your current approach. Sharing your current approach is good too, and make it clear you're open to 'better' alternatives.

If you're lucky, you end up [nerd sniping people](https://xkcd.com/356/)

In this case you got a few Bash scripts, Python and people performance testing different alternatives.

Comment: For sure on the Ubuntu site, and possibly on Unix&Linux, I've seen people ask "shell scripting" type questions, which get answered with a variety of standard programs, unless the question specified that one is unsuitable.